# Deleting a question with obvious content

Tags: discussion, deletion, deleted-questions

Few days ago I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599798/for-every-real-x0-there-are-y-z-in-mathbbr-such-that-x-yz-definiti), that a user – correctly – pointed out was not really the question I had in mind (that can now be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602082/how-to-derive-that-for-every-y-in-mathbbr-for-every-real-z-neq-1-ther)). Notice also that the answer is really (really!) obvious.

Should I delete the first question, or I should leave it, considering that apparently it has an interest in itself?

*[The statement concerning the interest does not come from the upvote, but from the fact that somebody favorited it]*

Thank you for your feedbacks.

---

**EDIT:**

Few minutes ago I realized that the first question (the "wrong" one) changed, in the sense that now I have the option either to say that the actual answer can be found in the second question (the "correct" one) or to edit the question.

The point is that true, the first question really got an answer in the second question, but just because I had wrongly phrased my first question. As it stands, my first question is that, and it has an answer. Hence, I do both options do not fit the situation. Indeed, everything should be left as it was (another question not particularly smart, with an answer).

What should I do?

Comment: The question has an upvoted and accepted answer, you can't delete it anyway. If it gets closed, three 10k+ users can delete it. While it's not closed, only moderators can delete it. (But we wouldn't, unless a good reason is given.)

Comment: [This meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20289/asked-a-trivial-question-got-a-simple-answer-was-put-on-hold-should-i-delete-i) is essentially the same, though it regards a question somewhat more poorly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should leave everything as it is, with the edit you added. Why? Because technically they are two different questions, even it's not the one you meant to ask in the first place.

Just because you find the answer "obvious" now doesn't mean that it's not challenging for other people who are not as experienced as you.

Most people here come to learn and help each other out. There is no stupid question unless it's evident that the user has made no effort to understand.